# PHP: print_r displays an array but when I use the array, the index is undefined

Tags: php

`print_r($post)` does display the associative array but when I try to get a specific index, the index is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```html
    <?php
    $title = 'Post Detail';
    include('_top.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/dao/PostDAO.php');
    //instantie van Klasse
    $postDAO = new PostDAO();
    //methode oproepen
    $post = $postDAO->getPostById();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($post);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
    <article>
      <header><h2><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h2></header>
      <?php echo $post['body']; ?>
    </article>
    
    <section class="comments">
      <header><h3>Comments</h3></header>
      <?php
      if (empty($comments)) {
        echo "<p>There are no comments for this post.</p>";
      } else {
        echo "<ol>";
        foreach( $comments as $comment ){
          echo "<li>";
          echo $comment['text'];
          echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ol>";
      }
      ?>
    </section>
    <?php include('_bottom.php');?>
```

I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/back-end/Lesweek 5/labo/startbestanden/14-exercise/post-detail.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: body in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/back-end/Lesweek 5/labo/startbestanden/14-exercise/post-detail.php on line 15
Comments
There are no comments for this post.
```

Comment: Show the actual output of print_r()

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [post_type_id] => 1
            [accepted_answer_id] => 32
            [creation_date] => 2010-08-17 19:35:07
            [score] => 4
            [view_count] => 94
            [body] => "some text..."
            [last_editor_user_id] => 0
            [last_edit_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [last_activity_date] => 2010-08-17 19:50:12
            [community_owned_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [title] => Multitasking on iPhone
           
        )

)
`

Comment: Your array is inside another array

Comment: It is `$post[0]['title']`.

Comment: Thanks guys, any idea why it's inside another array?

Comment: Figured it out myself, I used `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`. Thanks again for the help

Comment: That is how the only way is to put several posts.